# LLVM precompile concatenate issue

Tags: c, xcode, xcode5, llvm-clang

I concatenate my full app version using these macros:

```
#define MAJOR 3
#define BUILD 432

#define CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2)

#define VERSION CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(MAJOR, .), BUILD)
```

The output should be 3.432 and it worked perfectly until I recently updated to Xcode 5 and LLVM 5.1.
Now the output is: 3##.##432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several different preprocessor flags set and one of them was `-traditional`. This is the one that messed up things. After removing it everything went back to normal again.

> The # and ## operators are not available in traditional C.

See more [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html)